# How to remove node in D3 force layout?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a simple D3 simulation that looks like this

[image]

When I click the 'remove 1 and 4' button I want to remove nodes 1 and 4 from the simulation.  The result, however, is the following:

[image]

Visually it seems to have removed 3 and 4 (not 1 and 4).

My code is below.  Any ideas what I need to do to make this work correctly?

I'm assuming I've fundamentally misunderstood how updating nodes works in d3.  Any help appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<body>
<button>remove 1 and 4</button>
<script>

var width = 400,
    height = 400;

var nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4].map(function(x) { return { name: x}});

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(nodes) 
    .linkDistance(30)
    .charge(-500)
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
    
var content = svg.append("g");

var nodesData = force.nodes(),
    nodeElement = content.selectAll(".node");
   
function tick() {
    nodeElement.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

d3.selectAll('button').on('click', function() {

    //remove 1 and 4
    nodesData = [
        nodesData[1],
        nodesData[2]
    ]

    refresh();
});

var WIDTH = 100;

//
// this logic is slightly modified from http://bl.ocks.org/tgk/6068367
//
function refresh() {
    
    force.nodes(nodesData)

    nodeElement = nodeElement.data(nodesData);

    var nodeGroup = nodeElement.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr("class", "node");
            
    // node text
    nodeGroup.append("text")
        .attr("class", "nodetext")
        .attr("dx", WIDTH/2)
        .attr("dy", "14px")
        .text(function(n) { return 'node '+n.name })

    nodeElement.exit().remove();

    force.start();
}

refresh();

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem by adding a "key" function to the `.data` call inside the `refresh` function: `nodeElement = nodeElement.data(nodesData, function(d){ return d.name });`.

The problem you saw is not specific to updating nodes. Ordinarily, selections work based off of index of the data array. So if first D3 had `[a,b,c,d]` and now it has `[a,d]`, it's going to take the first two elements (`[a,b]`) unless you tell it the key that defines each item in the array. That's what the function above does.

For more see https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data